# Problem not display datetime field form in browser in django

Tags: python, django

What I can't see input datetime form.form django in my browser?

the program that I run in the browser,
The following code displayed instead of the input datetime

i have brought the codes of all the pages, please check

Thank you for your reply

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from  datetime import datetime

class ExpenseForm (forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'توضیحات' ,'class':'form-control'}),
        label='توضیحات',


    )
    date = forms.DateTimeField(
        initial=datetime.now(),
        widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={ 'placeholder':'تاریخ' ,
                                           'class':'form-control',
                                           'type': 'datetime-local'}),
        label='تاریخ',
    )


    amount = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder':'مقدار' ,'class':'form-control'}),
        label='مقدار'
    )
```

view.py

```
@login_required()
def submit_expense(request):
    expense_form = ExpenseForm(request.POST or None)
    if expense_form.is_valid():
        text = expense_form.cleaned_data.get('text')
        date =  expense_form.cleaned_data.get('date')
        amount = expense_form.cleaned_data.get('amount')

        Expense.objects.create(text=text , date=date , amount=amount , user_id=request.user.id)
        return redirect('/submit/expense')

    context ={
        'expense_form':expense_form
    }
    return render(request,'hello.html',context)
```

hello.html

```
{% extends 'shared/_MainLayout.html' %}

{% load static %}


{% block content %}
    <div class="login-form"><!--expense form-->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="login-form"><!--expense form-->
            <h2>پولهای خرج شده :</h2>
            <form method="post" action="#">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ expense_form.text }}

                {{ expense_form.amount }}

                {{ expense_form.data }}

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">ثبت</button>
            </form>
        </div><!--/login form-->
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

please check the image to see my problem

[browser page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhKVP.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wrote `{{ expense_form.data }}` instead of `{{ expense_form.date }}`